# Laravel postgresql error handling

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to laravel and I couldn't find an answer to the problem in the documentation nor google. So here it is:

I have to use a vpn connection to connect to the postgresql database. If I'n not connected laravel gives me the following error:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection timed
>   out.....

How do I tell laravel to ignore that error and instead just return a message "no connection"?

```
$export = DB::connection('pgsql')->select("SOME SQL");
```

I tried the "@" before the DB, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your routes.php (top of it) or your start.php:

```
App::error(function(\Exception $e)
{
    return "Error handled!";
});
```

And try again:

```
$export = DB::connection('pgsql')->select("SOME SQL");
```

It will catch the error and now you can do whatever you need with it.

If you return null from that error handler, Laravel will catch the error and do what it is doing now.